# Error during ant startting

Tags: java, unix, ant

I want to run ant as:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xmx512m -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl -classpath $TEST_HOME/implementation/lib/dbflux3.1.5.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$CLASSPATH org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile build.xml $*
```

My CLASSPATH variable is

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

/opt/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0/lib/ant.jar

When I am starting ant.sh as

```
./ant.sh test
```

I get error:

```
The java class is not found:  org/apache/tools/ant/launch/AntMain
```

How can I fix it? Or where is I can read about it?

I read JDK Development tools documenation, but didn't find answer for my issue.

Thanks.

Update.

Thanks for help Suresh Sajja.
The answer might be found on

https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

Running Ant via Java

Comment: Check running Ant via Java  : https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

Comment: Okay, thank. I will read now.

Comment: if i am running as "ant" I see working ant. It begins building default build.xml. But if I start ant via my script I am getting same error as in my question.

Comment: did you set ant.home property?  "java -Dant.home=c:\ant org.apache.tools.ant.Main [options] [target]"

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean about ant.home property? Where is I can read about it? I set ANT_HOME:echo $ANT_HOME
/opt/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0

Comment: last section of the document that referred earlier contains all the details. Go through it once, If it is not working for you. let me know

Comment: Suresh Sajja, thanks you a lot. It help me. I think this is solution of my issue.